# Error: There was a problem getting the Conversation associated with this room

Tags: reactjs, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-video

I'm trying to implement this project: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video-app-react

I got error "There was a problem getting the Conversation associated with this room." when the `ChatProvider` did mount. Seem like `chatClient` can't find the conversation with `room.sid` but I can't figure out how to create conversation when it doesn't exist and add participants when conversation existed. Does anyone know this issue? Thanks!

Update: the server code: https://gist.github.com/qngnud/c9910afada625a9a4eceb3ad3a67d3b7

Comment: Have you set the `TWILIO_CONVERSATIONS_SERVICE_SID` in the env file? Are there errors on the server side that you can share?

Comment: @philnash Hi, sorry about reply lately, I write all my id, token directly into my code and my server doesn't show any error, this is my server code: https://gist.github.com/qngnud/c9910afada625a9a4eceb3ad3a67d3b7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It appears that you are using similar code to the original app in your server, however you have missed a crucial keyword.

The part of the code where you try to fetch a conversation by the room.sid is surrounded by a try/catch, however it is called in promise form, so any failures will be picked up by a chained `.catch()` function.

In the [original code](https://github.com/twilio-labs/plugin-rtc/blob/master/src/serverless/functions/token.js), the calls are made using the `await` keyword which turns promises into code that appears synchronous and, most importantly, in which errors can be caught by a try/catch block.

So, you should either move your `catch` blocks to `.catch()` promise chains, or declare the whole function `async` and use `await` before the asynchronous function calls.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by adding member in the channel before joining the twilio room.

To add member in the channel, I used the api provided by twilio => [Click here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/rest/member-resource).

After adding the member in the channel, ChatClient will find the conversation with roomSid.

And I used `chatClient.getConversationBySid('CHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')` instead `chatClient.getConversationByUniqueName(room.sid)`.

Happy Coding!